# Speaker Recognition - Verification - How can we verify if we have more than 100 profiles

Tags: speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

During Speaker verification, we need to pass verificationProfileId as a parameter to the API. let us assume that we have 100 profiles enrolled. do we need call the Verification API 100 times to verify the user by passing verificationProfileId or is there a method to verrify without passing verificationProfileId

Thanks,
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

Think of speaker verification as a form of [2FA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication). Speaker verification should **not** be the main form of authentication of a user.

Let's say that you are creating a user database. When a user comes in you take their username and password and then [enroll](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/56406930e597ed20c8d8549c) the user with the audio samples. When the enrollment is complete you can map a unique username to a unique [profile ID](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/56409ee2778daf19706420de).

When the user comes back, you take in the username/password and you know their profile ID. You get an audio sample from them and then you just call the [/verify](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/56406930e597ed20c8d8549d) endpoint with the profile ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the “GetAllProfiles” API to return a list of all the successfully created profiles, given that they are all created using the same subscription key.

You can refer to [Speaker Recognition API: Verification Profile - Get All Profiles](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/563309b7778daf06340c9653) .